# Issue with provisioned profile in IOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am truing to run my application in my iPhone, I am getting the following error. 
No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

Note that, I am truing to run my application in IOS 7.1.2
Xcode Version 5.0.2 (5A3005)

I have added the provision profile for the 5 months back and yesterday I have updated the os version to 7.1.2. Is it necessary to agin create a provision profile to the mobile? and also I noticed that in Project info tab under Deployment target I din't find IOS version 7.1 so Have selected 7.0 this may causes any issues?

Give me some suggestions to solve the issue.

Comment: I think xcode 5.1.1 is required. #

Comment: so shall I update my Xcode?

Comment: yes. I would try this at first.

Comment: I have Xcode 5.1.1 and still the same problem.